# How to stop the rotation of an activity only for a specific fragment in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tablayout

I have an activity in which I have added a `TabLayout`. Each tab contains a fragment. I want to block the rotation only in a single fragment, not in all. This is the code that I'm using in a single fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

But it stops the rotation in every fragment. How to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to override `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` in the Fragment to know when the fragment is actually shown, eg. :

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser && null != activity) { 
 activity.setRequestedOrientation(
  ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
else if(!isVisibleToUser && null != activity) {
 activity.setRequestedOrientation(
  ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
  }
 }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint

Or put it elsewhere than `onResume()/onPause()` and where the activity will not be null, eg. `onAttach()`

Comment: Using `setUserVisibleHint` solved my problem. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onPause` method to allow every orientation in your activities using [SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

---

A bit deeper:

You don't have to specify nothing in your activity, but just work with fragment.

In your fragment use onResume and onPause methods like follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

and it should work

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.. So I should add this in the  activity or fragment?

Comment: No problem! just try replacing your onPause code with the one above, it should work fine in fragment :)

Comment: I have added that code in the activity and changed `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` in fragment bu it doesn't work.

Comment: I did that and it doesn't work. The other fragments are also blocked.

Comment: try debugging and check if onPause is called in your fragment, don't specify nothing in your activity, just work with fragment (I edited answer)

Comment: For some reasons, either `onResume` nor `onPause` are triggered so I solved the problem with User One's answer. Voted-up for providing `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` which solved the else part. Thank you!